# Read data by rows from ResultSet

Tags: java, postgresql, resultset

I have the following question, is it possible to read the data from result set by rows? For example if I have read 12 rows by the following statement:

```
select * from months where data = 'whatever' and place_id = '1'
```

I can read the data into a string by following code:

```
while (rs.next()) 
{
    for ( int i=1, y=0; i<numOfCols+1; i++,y++ ) 
{
    out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(i) + "</td>");
        avMaxTemp += rs.getString(i) +",";
    }
}
```

If I change the select statement:

```
select * from months where data = 'whatever' and place_id in ('1', '2')
```

How will I read the second row of data into:

```
string avMinTemp =
```

I tried a lot to play with the loop(s) but it never gave me the results expected. Any help greatly appriciated!!! I need to copy the second row into a string avMinTemp, the third row of data into string meanTemp and so on...

Comment: What programming language is it? Update your question tags, please.

Comment: Its java, tha database is postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a list object before the while statement and add avaMaxTemp to this list (assuming avaMaxTemp is a string)

e.g.:

```
List<string> avaMaxTempList = new List<string>();
while (rs.next()) 
{
    for ( int i=1, y=0; i<numOfCols+1; i++,y++ ) 
{
    out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(i) + "</td>");
        avMaxTemp += rs.getString(i) +",";
    }
avaMaxTempList.Add(avaMaxTemp);
}
```

Comment: Thaks for reply! You probably did not get the question... The piece of code above is fine - it works! However I want to copy a second row into a string avMinTemp, then third row int meanTemp etc.

Comment: Do you have a list of all variables (row names)? e.g.
-avaMaxTemp
-avaMinTemp
-meanTemp
- etc

Comment: No - I dont have the list - so in order to do what I want I have to have a list do I!?

Comment: Yes, you need a key value.
Best thing would be to create a "key"-"value" pair, like a dictionary, whereby the "key" your variable is (e.g. avaMaxTemp) and "value" the concatenated string (e.g. += rs.getString(i) +",")

Hope this can be helpful, otherwise please deliver more information.

Comment: On the line where: List<string> avaMaxTempList = new List<string>(); I get an error: string cannot be resolved to a type... I included java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList in my jsp. Do you know what could that be?

Comment: Got it with few modifications! Thanks!

Comment: The following link uses rs.absolute(n) to get nth row.
https://www.javatpoint.com/ResultSet-interface